# Compiler does not wait for the result before executing the next line in the ValueEventListener

Tags: android

Here is the code which I have written

```
dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
for(DataSnapshot snap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    gr = snap.getKey();
    a: dbref.child(gr).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
            if (dataSnapshot1.hasChild(uid)) {
                grp = gr;
                got = 1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });

    if(got == 1) {
        got = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

I want that the code under the **ValueEventListener** to be executed according to the flow but compiler executes only line 'a' (marked above) until the loop ends and then executes the code under the listener. Can anyone please help me solve that problem.

Comment: "Compiler not wait"? Because you set a listener and its an Asynchronous call so it will call one of its method on completion. You need to put break point inside callback methods .

Comment: @ADM can you please give me an example